# How to fix icons of kyslik/column-sortable

Tags: laravel

I use kyslik/column-sortable in laravel but i can prevent changing sorting icons in header. I want to fix default icon is "fa fa-sort-asc" and "fa fa-sort-desc", prevent change to "fa fa-sort-alpha-asc" based on value.
I found that "columnsortable.php" file has spec columns config, but i do not how to set config in blade file.

```
@sortablelink('created_at', 'Created_at', ['prefix' => 'user'])
```

Anyone help me, please!

Comment: what is error/question here ?

Comment: @AliRaza I want to fix icons of all columns "fa fa-sort-asc", not "fa fa-sort-alpha-asc"